# Add/remove focus in ui-select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, focus, ui-select

Since yesterday I'm trying to accomplish as follows. I have a `ui-select` element which for a use case it needs to have the focus whenever the page is load. As I see in the [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select) this can be done setting up the autofocus in the directive but what I actually need is to swap the focus to a input text whenever I click a button and viceversa if input text is focused to the ui-select again. This not a problem when it deals to change the focus from `ui-select` to input text doing simply:

```
$("#txt-test").focus();
```

But in the other case, not works simply putting on:

```
$("#cbx").focus();
```

Where `#cbx` is the id for the `ui-select`. No matter how I try, it never gets the focus.

You can see the example here of what I'm trying to accomplish: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tonetete/bkht2cee/33/)

Any ideas? Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$scope.clickButton = function(){     
  var result = document.getElementById("cbx");
  var uiSelect = angular.element(result).controller('uiSelect');
  uiSelect.focusser[0].focus();
  uiSelect.open = true;
  uiSelect.activate();
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bkht2cee/34/)